# Where to ask a question about ads I see on different site when I browse on a shopping site? Or has it been already asked?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I just want to understand like when I search a GPU on any reputed shopping website, why each and every website like any news website (including social media) is flooded with ads from well known ad companies (e.g. Google ads) with "Discounts on GPU Shop Now".

For example, I search for a GPU on Amazon. Then I visit another website which has nothing to do with shopping will show me Google ads related to GPU.

It's been bothering me for 2-3 years but I could not find a good and easy to understand resource.

I know it involves cookies but they are private to its own domain so I literally don't understand it. I can find many blogs written on this topic but they don't exactly explain how it works.

I have done my own basic research but it didn't help me. Maybe I'm not good enough so I definitely need "help" from someone else who can explain it in easy terms.

I don't want to go into too much technical details because I'm not programmer right now, but yeah I know basics of cookies that I learned with PHP and JavaScript. But I'm no longer active in programming.

So the simpler the explanation (that is less technical / less coding based answer), easier it would be for me to understand.

However, I wouldn't mind to read existing answers/resources if they already exist irrespective of they are complex/technical. Maybe I can understand something from them.

I really think it's a genuine question and should be asked (or may have been already asked).

So where can I ask it if it hasn't been asked before? And would it be on topic?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+do+advertisers+know+what+I+have+searched+for&t=brave&ia=web seems to bring up some good hits, though none particularly in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+advertisers+know+what+I+search+for+site%3Astackexchange.com brings up several related questions on [security.se] including [Do advertisers listen as we talk?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235163/), [Is Google spying on all of us?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/) and [How did Google know I looked something up?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171055/) though none specifically about the bigger picture you are asking about.

Comment: This might be on topic at Super User. [This question asks about how to block it](https://superuser.com/questions/886917/block-contextual-ads-based-on-browser-activity-from-google/886975) so maybe a question asking how it works would be OK? I'm not sure if it would be considered too close to a programming question so check their [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [meta](https://meta.superuser.com/).

Comment: It'd help to know how technical you want the explanation.

Comment: Was what you Posted, what you really meant? Could you - could anyone - re-phrase "… like when I search a GPU on any reputed shopping website, why each and every website like any news website (including social media) is flooded with ads from well known ad companies (e.g. Google ads) with 'Discounts on GPU Shop Now' " to give it clear or useful meaning?